# Erro Cannot read property 'map' of undefined no browse (Angular)

Tags: angular

Olá,
Quando eu acesso a minha página, aparece o erro no browse: Ocorreu um erro TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. 
O meu código que contem a chamada .map() está assim:

```
export class LancamentoCadastroComponent implements OnInit {

categorias = [];  

constructor(private categoriaService: CategoriaService,
          private errorHandler: ErrorHandlerService) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.carregarCategorias();


carregarCategorias() {
return this.categoriaService.listarTodas()
  .then(categorias => {
    this.categorias = categorias.map(c => ({ label: c.nome, value: c.codigo }));
  })
  .catch(erro => this.errorHandler.handle(erro));
}
}
```

Até aparece para mim uma mensagem no errorHandler no meu else. 
O errorHandler está assim:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorHandlerService {


constructor(private toasty: ToastyService) { }

handle(errorResponse: any) {
let msg: string;

if (typeof errorResponse === 'string') {
  msg = errorResponse;

} else if (errorResponse instanceof Response
    && errorResponse.status >= 400 && errorResponse.status <= 499) {
  let errors;
  msg = 'Ocorreu um erro ao processar a sua solicitação';

  try {
    errors = errorResponse.json();

    msg = errors[0].mensagemUsuario;
  } catch (e) { }

  console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);

} else {
  msg = 'Erro ao processar serviço remoto. Tente novamente.';
  console.error('Ocorreu um erro', errorResponse);
}

this.toasty.error(msg);
}
}
```

Poderiam, por favor, me dar um norte onde eu estou errando? Dá a entender que não conhece esse método .map().
Obrigado.

Comment: Caro Victor, `listarTodas` esta retornando vazio e por isso .map não vai funcionar, porque o then não conseguiu obter nada, vá até o metodo `listarTodas` na classe `CategoriaService` e corrija isto.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, obrigado pelo retorno. Chequei isso e, realmente, estava faltando um import (import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'). Obrigado pelo auxílio. Há alguma forma de eu conseguir um retorno mais específico para este caso? Por exemplo, ter uma mensagem de erro falando 'o map está vazio' ou algo assim? Obrigado!

Comment: Mas o problema não é no map, como eu disse antes, é no then, ou melhor, no que envia para o teu promise, logo bastaria checar se o valor enviado no then é "vazio", tipo algo como: `if (!categorias || !categorias.length) { ... mensagem de erro ...} else { this.categorias = categorias.map(c => ({ label: c.nome, value: c.codigo })); }`, aliais deve ter algo bem errado na tua classe, porque se estivesse "correto" era para  cair no CATCH e não no THEN.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrado o problema:

Estava faltando um import:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
```

em categoria.service.ts
Cheguei nesse resultado após o retorno do @Guilherme Nascimento me responder que o .map() estava vazio.